# How to convert Array of values in VBA to array of other value types, based on user input?

Tags: arrays, vba

So I have an class returns array of singles. Problem is that new requrement came up where I need to be able provide these values as a single string, which can be done with `Join` except `Join` requres that array is made up of strings not singles.

I guess I could write a new method in my class that provides same array but with values as strings. However I was wondering if I could just convert existing method to accept something like `Optional ValType as vbVarType` as a parameter and accordingly change the type of values in ouputed array.

Is this doable in a relatively DRY way?? I'd love to avoid code that looks like:

```
Select Case ValType
    Case #something1
        #omitted code
    Case #something2
        #omitted codev
    Case #something3
        #omitted code
    ........
```

UPDATE: I guess what I am looking for is a formula like `Cstr()` except that I'd like it to work on an Array and have it expect parameeter describing value to convert to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply have an array of type `Variant` rather than `Single`? The following code seems to work ok:

```
Dim arrInt() As Variant

ReDim arrInt(0 To 3)

arrInt(0) = 0
arrInt(1) = 1
arrInt(2) = 2
arrInt(3) = 3

Debug.Print Join(arrInt, "#")
```